# GLM with scores/principal dimensions from MCA

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, glmm, correspondence-analysis

I hope someone can help me understand how to run this analysis!

I have a dataset with many categorical variables (i.e. color, pattern, texture) associated to each animal in each interaction between pairs of animals (a set of categorical variables for each interaction of each animal in each pair).
I want to test the effect of each variable on animal contest outcome (binomial).

My sample size is really small compared to the number of variables/predictors (n = 10 pairs composed by 5 animals in total).

So, I would like to perform a "Multiple Correspondence analysis" (MCA) to reduce the dimensionality and select only the most relevant predictor variables to input in a Generalised Linear Mixed Effect Model (GLMM). This would also allow me to avoid including in the same GLMM model predictors with high collinearity, is that correct?

I read that you can input the scores from a PCA into a GLM with Factoextra.
Can you do the same with the scores from a MCA? Could I simply input the scores from the dimensions in the MCA into a GLMM model with lma4:glmer R function?

This would be the model with the original variables:

```r
glmer(outcome ~ body color + texture + pattern + 
                (1|individual_ID) + (1|pair_ID), 
                family=binomial(link="logit"), dataset)
```

How would the model with the MCA scores look like?

If I input the MCA scores in the GLMM model, can I still know which original variable (i.e. color) is the strongest predictor of contest outcome?

I haven't found much information on how to run a GLMM with MCA scores, so any help including tutorial links or examples that you could recommend would be highly appreciated!

Comment: See https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jar/2013/302163/  for a paper combining mca, pca with regression analysis

Answer (score 1):

Using the factors obtained in the MCA as predictors in GLM/GLMM is valid, especially considering your specific case (need for dimension reduction and multicolinearity reduction).

The interpretation of the coefficients will be the difficult part. I would try two approaches:

1. Having a good understanding and labelling of each factor, and interpreting the coefficients only in relative terms: "The augmentation of this factor is associated with a decrease (or increase) in my output".
2. Using model predictions and marginal effects. The idea is to have an observation used as a scenario, using the function `predict.MCA` from `factoMineR` to get is coordinates on the new factors and then predicting your outcome with the `predict` function and your GLM/GLMM. You can then do the same thing but with a new observation for which you change only one characteristic (scenario 2). You can then interpret the change between the two predictions. But keep in mind that it is not exactly "everything hold equal" because changing that characteristic will affect the other factors.

A last suggestion would be to think about your process (input data --> MCA --> GLMM --> result) as a global model. With a little bit of effort, you could use the functions from DALEX and analyze your whole model with tools used in machine learning.

Comment: What is DALEX? ...

Comment: another R library for interpreting machine learning models: https://uc-r.github.io/dalex

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you so much for your detailed reply and explanation.
I have been looking into this and asking around, and as far as I understood MCA creates new variables which could be given by 20% of the categorical variable A (i.e. color) and 50% by the categorical variable B (i.e. pattern). So that it would be a bit complicated to extract conlusions about the main effect of each categorical predictor from a MCA - gLMM analysis. Is that correct?

Comment: Would a Cluster analysis and then GLMM be better? As far as I understood Cluster Analysis does not create new variables like PCA/MCA but only groups together variables that are collinear or explain the variance in the dependent variable in a similar way...is that correct?

Comment: I have also been suggested recently to drop the GLMM model approach altogether, and use instead "Conditional Inference Models" which are better suited for small sample sizes & large number of categorical variables as in my case...do you think that would be a better approach?

I would really appreciate some advice & tutorial links as I feel a bit lost at the moment.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cluster Analysis does not aim to group variables but observations. The goal it to obtain groups of individuals that are similar. You would obtain a new categorical variable that will indicate for each observation to which group it belongs. I am not sure it would help you in that context. If I understand well, you have only 50 observations (5 * 10) ? This is a very low number to use factor analysis (MCA) and GLMM. Maybe using only bivariate tests between your Y and X variables would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,and thanks again for replying.
I have over 300 observations, because I have repeated observations for each individual. So I guess I could try and use MCA first and see if specific groups of individual traits consistently explain variance in the dependent variable..?
I am also trying to eliminate collinear variavbles first, but I am having a hard time to find a function in R for multiple pairwise correlations between a bunch of categorical variables..thank again for you help!

Comment: Hi , just another doubt...I haven't found any example of how to use the MCA dimensions in a GLM model. I found examples only for PCA, where they include the individuals coordinate `score= as_tibble(factoextra::get_pca_ind(pca)$coord)` in the GLM. But with MCA would you use the coordinates of the variables categories (and not the individuals/observations coordinates) as dimensions scores to input in the GLM?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @Dory33. You can use the coordinates of the individual of the MCA as predictors in your GLMM. Using the coordinates of the modalities would not make much sens. 300 observations sounds reasonable (depending on the number of categorical variables and their modalities).

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! it seemed to have worked! Yes, I tried using the variables coordinate but it doesn't work with that because the data has then different length (var coordinates are not 300 as the observations) and I guess it makes more sense to use the observations. With dimdesc() I can see which are the variable categories that are significantly correlated with each Dimension.

Comment: Now, if I see that a series of variables (i.e. yellow color, stripes and standing) are significantly correlated with Dimension 1 and Dimension 1 predicts my dependent variable in a GLMM model, then I can also say that yellow, stripes and standing predict or are more highly associated with my dependent variable, is that correct?  Thanks anyways for all your help so far, really appreciated!

Comment: yes, you could say that. To have a better understanding on their effect, you could also do something like:
1) take one of your obseravtions (with the original variables)
2) predict its coordinates with the results of the MCA
3) predict the value expected from your GLMM on that observation by using the MCA coordinates
5) create a new observation (scenario) by changing by example the color of that observation
6) predict the coordinates of that new observations with the MCA
7) predict the expected output with your GLMM for it
And then compare the two predictions.